# react native not finish "Installing the app"

Tags: node.js, react-native

I created the new project with the following command:

`npx react-native init AwesomeProject`

And I executed the project with the following command:

`npx react-native run-android`

After executing the above code, it shows the following text in cmd:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 870 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
```

After a few minutes, the installation will not be done and it will remain in the same condition.

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command in order to see whats happening during initialization

```
react-native init projectname --verbose
```